# Python - Error in String literal str.replace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have attempted to replace a `string` in a column with either of the two commands below. For both of them, I am getting the "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" error. Please help/guide. Thanks.

```
df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.replace("H:\May2017\hb_ymvid\HB_ED_S\Pictures1\05cropped_PC\","", inplace=True)
df["filename"] = df["filename"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("H:\May2017\hb_ymvid\HB_ED_S\Pictures1\05cropped_PC\", ""))
```

Comment: I think it's because of the last `\"` in path names. Better to use path names as raw strings

Comment: You are putting a literal `"` into your path string and then never terminate the string.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM raw strings must not end with ``\`` either, see last paragraph in this part of the docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: The first line wouldn't run anyway since [pd.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) doesn't have an `inplace` method.

Comment: @vtasca - You are correct.. Thanks.

Comment: In general, you don't have to use backslashes in path names, Windows will accept forward slashes as well.

Comment: Do you want to remove a prefix path from your column `filename`?

Comment: @Corralien , Yes. the Dataframe column has a full path of a file. I want to remove the prefix path and have only the filename. (Please see sample data below.)

Comment: How do you build your dataframe? Maybe you should extract the basename early in your process?

Comment: @Corralien, I agree that it should be done upfront. But assuming that a column has file name strings of this type, what would be approach to retain only the basename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.replace` with `regex=False` because you don't use a regex:

```
root_dir = 'H:\\May2017\\hb_ymvid\\HB_ED_S\\Pictures1\\05cropped_PC\\'

df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.replace(root_dir, '', regex=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      filename
0  image01.png
1  image02.png
```

I used this sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': [r"H:\May2017\hb_ymvid\HB_ED_S\Pictures1\05cropped_PC\image01.png",
                                r"H:\May2017\hb_ymvid\HB_ED_S\Pictures1\05cropped_PC\image02.png"]})
print(df)

# Output
                                            filename
0  H:\May2017\hb_ymvid\HB_ED_S\Pictures1\05croppe...
1  H:\May2017\hb_ymvid\HB_ED_S\Pictures1\05croppe...
```

Comment: @user1955215. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: instead of removing a *specific* directory path, wouldn't it be more useful to split the filename into parts and only retain the last part? To make this even more reliable (and versatile) I'd suggest working with [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) objects.

Comment: @MrFuppes. I have already tested this solution and it worked but I'm working on Linux and WindowsPath is not available... Your idea to keep the last part does not work if there are subdirectories.

Comment: I mean this *works*, I'm just saying it could be made applicable more generally ;-)

Comment: concerning your remark on subdirs, that's exactly why I'd use pathlib to handle the like

Comment: @Corralien Thanks a ton, It works. Sorry for the delay in response. Was caught up with something else.

Answer (score 0):

`\` denotes escape sequence in `python`, if you mean literal `\` then use `\\`, i.e. replace

```
"H:\May2017\hb_ymvid\HB_ED_S\Pictures1\05cropped_PC\"
```

using

```
"H:\\May2017\\hb_ymvid\\HB_ED_S\\Pictures1\\05cropped_PC\\"
```

and so on

Comment: I tried with this df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.replace("H:\\May2017\\hb_ymvid\\HB_ED_S\\Pictures1\\05cropped_PC\\",""),  it is returning a "error: bad escape \M at position 2" error

Comment: To elaborate on what I am attempting: 
The dataframe column has strings like this: "H:\May2017\hb_ymvid\HB_ED_S\Pictures1\05cropped_PC\1272.txt"
I want to remove the path and retain only the file name ie "1272.txt"